# Print the area of the polygon which is apothem*perimeter

Tags: python, oop

```
from cmath import tan
import math

class mainClass(object):
    def __init__(self, No_of_sides, length_of_sides):
        self.No_of_sides = No_of_sides
        self.length_of_sides = length_of_sides

    def peri(self): #This is the perimeter method
        p = self.No_of_sides*self.length_of_sides
        return p
    
    def apothem_(self): #This is the apothem method
        apo = self.length_of_sides/ (2* tan (180/self.No_of_sides))
        return apo
```

I am trying to print the area of the polygon in this class:

```
class areaclass(object): 
    def area_ (self):
        obj = mainClass()
        data1 = obj.apothem_()
        data2 = obj.peri()
        area = data1*data2
        print("The area of the polygon is: ", area)
        

mc = mainClass( No_of_sides = float(input("What is the no of polygon sides: ")),
            length_of_sides = float(input("What is the length of each side: ")))


ac=areaclass()
```

Comment: whats the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

The only instance of `mainClass` you are instantiating with values is `mc` when it is called by `ac=areclass` no values are provided to `mainClass` for `No_of_sides, length_of_sides`

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed your code and I believe that you need to rework the code a bit to perform the area calculation.  Following is a copy of your code with some revisions.

```
from cmath import tan
import math
import cmath

class mainClass(object):
    def __init__(self, No_of_sides, length_of_sides):
        self.No_of_sides = No_of_sides
        self.length_of_sides = length_of_sides

    def peri(self): #This is the perimeter method
        p = self.No_of_sides*self.length_of_sides
        return p
    
    def apothem_(self): #This is the apothem method
        apo = self.length_of_sides/ (4 * tan (math.pi/self.No_of_sides))
        return apo
        
class areaclass(object): 
    
    def area_ (self, obj):
        data1 = obj.apothem_()
        data2 = obj.peri()
        area = data1*data2
        print("The area of the polygon is: ", area)
        return area.real

mc = mainClass(int(input("What is the no of polygon sides: ")), float(input("What is the length of each side: ")))

ac = areaclass()
            
print(ac.area_(mc))
```

Some of the main points to note:

- The master class object really needs to be passed as a parameter to the "area_" function so that the function within the class references an object and not a class.
- In testing out the "apo" calculation, I found that I needed to revise the denominator to use a constant of "4" and use the value of "math.pi" as the tangent function is expecting radians.

With that, testing out various regular polygons for area appeared to calculate the proper area.

Give that a try if you would.  No doubt, there are other bits you can do to polish this up.  FYI, the "apo" formula returns a complex number but the "imaginary" part does come back as zero.  You might want to check out just extracting the "real" number portion as that is the value you would want.